# Javascript: Draw shape with width and height of image

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I currently have a canvas on which I draw 4 "shapes" which are displayed as an image.
The code for making the shapes:

```
  function init() {
  var s = new CanvasState(document.getElementById('canvas1'));
  s.addShape(new Shape(40,40,180,180)); // The default is gray
  s.addShape(new Shape(60,140,40,60, 'lightskyblue'));
  // Some partially transparent
  s.addShape(new Shape(80,150,60,30, 'rgba(127, 255, 212, .5)'));
  s.addShape(new Shape(125,80,30,80, 'rgba(245, 222, 179, .7)'));
}
```

And drawing the shapes:

```
Shape.prototype.draw = function(ctx) {
        var locx = this.x;
        var locy = this.y;
        var imgNew = new Image();
        imgNew.onload = function(){ 
            ctx.drawImage(imgNew, locx, locy);

        }
        imgNew.src = "upload/Evenredig.jpg";
}
```

As you can see I am currently setting the width and height of the shape manually but I would like to know if it is possible to get the width and height from the image and set that as the width and height of the shape.

The full code for the canvas can be found here (It may be helpfull??)
http://pastebin.com/Z3eqvVnw

ps. feel free to edit the title if you know a better one because I have no idea how to name this question.

Comment: `imgNew.width` and `imgNew.height`

Comment: @fzzle can you be a bit more clear? Where exactly would you suggest I use this?